PyQt 5 application crashes and/or malfunctions for unknown reasons
So, I have a program where there is a list widget filled with items. Upon double-clicking (activation) on the item, a message appears and then the item disappears, and if I click on the "Load!" button on the app, the item should not reappear. There are just two problems however. While the "Load!" button seems to always work perfectly, activating an item can sometimes cause the GUI to crash, and if it doesn't crash, for some reason, it sometimes activates two items one after the other. When it doesn't crash and doesn't activate two items at once, it works exactly as expected. When the GUI crashes, no traceback can be seen.
The connections for the list items and the button:
def on_item_activated(item):
    setting(item, listWidget, feed, dict1, dictQ)

listWidget.itemActivated.connect(on_item_activated)
button = QPushButton("Load!")

def viewer():
    viewing(feed, listWidget, dict1)
btnconnect = button.clicked.connect(viewer)

What clicking on the item/button does:
def moveToQ(entryDel, listWidget, dict1, dictQ):
    dictQ[entryDel] = dict1[entryDel]
    del dict1[entryDel] 
    row = 0
    listWidget.clearSelection()
    listWidget.clear()
    for i in list(dict1.keys()):
        #print("Hi")
        listWidget.insertItem(row, i)
        row += 1

def setting(item, widget, feed, dict1, dictQ):
    message = QMessageBox()
    for entry in list(dict1.keys()):
        
        if (item.text() == entry):
            message.setText(dict1[entry])
            message.exec_()
            moveToQ(entry, widget, dict1, dictQ)

def viewing(feed, listWidget, dict1):
    #print("Hi")
    listWidget.clear()
    row = 0
    for x in list(dict1.keys()):
        listWidget.insertItem(row, x)
        row += 1

I initially used lambda functions for the connections. After finding suggestions to use slots instead, I switched away from lambda functions. However, the results remained unchanged.

There's nothing wrong in using lambdas, as long as they're used for the correct reason, and, actually, what you're doing is not that different. The fact is that, while not wrong nor technically invalid, using pure functions and working with global objects is normally discouraged, as it makes implementation and debugging more difficult, at least for specifically OOP languages and toolkits like Python and Qt, for which subclassing is the preferred and suggested approach. In any case, it seems unlikely that you get absolutely no traceback at all: are you running the code in a terminal/prompt?

The QListWidget.clear slot permanently deletes every item. So when setting finds a match , moveToQ will clear the current list, including the activated item. But then the search will pointlessly continue, meaning the text method gets called again on an already deleted item, resulting in a crash. As has already been pointed out, part of the problem here is the use of globals. However, even worse is the highly redundant code structure: there's no need to search and re-populate a list-widget just to delete the selected item.

@ekhumoro Thanks. I'll try just returning before the search continues. And I'll try my best to reduce the redundancy.

@musicamante To add some more context here, I was actually steering away from global variables and just passing parametres to all functions. I was indeed running the code in a terminal. So normally, if an error were to occur, I'd see it, but in this particular case, the program just crashes/malfunctions and I see nothing.

@emipy No problem. Glad you got it working. (PS: please don't edit the title of your questions and add words like "resolved". If you found your own solution, please either post an answer, or if was something trivial, just delete the question).

@ekhumoro Got it.

Based on ekhumoro's comment, I tried just returning before the search continues, and it worked.

The QListWidget.clear slot permanently deletes every item. So when setting finds a match, moveToQ will clear the current list, including the activated item. But then the search will pointlessly continue, meaning the text method gets called again on an already deleted item, resulting in a crash. As has already been pointed out, part of the problem here is the use of globals. However, even worse is the highly redundant code structure: there's no need to search and re-populate a list-widget just to delete the selected item.

